# jQuery - POST data to iframe and redirect after iframe has finish loading

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, iframe

Here is what I have so far:

```
<?php

// Simulating some post values for test proposes
$_POST['test'] = 'testing values';

// POST contents (originally from a form in another page)
$query = http_build_query( $_POST );

?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { $("#myiframe").load(function(){ window.location.replace('after.php'); }); });
 </script>
 <title>iFrame Load POST</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="myiframe" src="load.php" width="0" height="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

What I need is to be able to send $_POST data, originally sent from a form in another page, to the iframe and redirect the page after the iframe has loaded and processed the post data.

**---- EDIT ----**

In fact, it doesn't need an iframe, but I still need to do a post call to load.php and wait for it to load in order to make the redirect. I cannot redirect before the load.php has finish loading the request. That's why I was using the iframe method and previously using GET instead of POST.

**--------------**

Can someone please help?

Thank you!

Comment: Why do you need to do the post into an iframe, if you just intend to redirect once the request is finished (i.e., you're not doing anything with the content you just loaded)? Are you trying to bypass a cross-domain issue? If not, a plain AJAX call would do.

Comment: It can be that way yes, the iframe is in fact not needed.

Comment: Everything is on the same domain.

Comment: Have you considered posting to the same page and executing the code that would have been on your load.php and just handle it from there?

Comment: It can't be, because this happens in a loading popup that get's POST data from a form in a parent window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a jQuery AJAX call. It allows you to attach a handler that gets executed once the request finishes successfully.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'load.php',
    data: {foo: 'bar'},
    type: 'post', // you can use get if you want to.
    success: function(response) {
        window.location.replace('after.php'); 
    }
});
```